# Python: convert str to int inside a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I am learning about recursive functions and I have made a simple "*string to ASCII*" converter which returns the ASCII value of each character of a string.

Here is what I have made so far:

```
def cod(n):
    if n == "":
        return "" 
    else:
        a = str(ord(n[0])) + cod(n[1:])
        return a
```

This works fine like this:

```
=> cod('hello')
=> '104101108108111'
```

The problem is when I am trying to get an `int` as output instead of a `string`. I can't simply convert variable `a` because it's a recursive function, and it's not possible to iterate over an int.

After this point I am a little lost, can someone point out how to get an int as a final result of this recursive function?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Why do you need to convert `a`?

Comment: On the example i gave 'cod('hello')', it's the same '104101108108111' but in int format instead of str...

Comment: Make `cod` return integers. Have it return `0` if `n == ""` and also convert `cod` to an `str` before adding. Then convert `a` to an `int`.

Comment: Do you want to return the sum of `ord` or to cast the string into an `int` at the end? i.e. is your desired output `104101108108111` or `532`?

Comment: @VincentSavard, is to cast the string into an int at the end, getting the output `104101108108111`

Comment: @PeterWood that's it! I can't belive how simple it was, i was really off. thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def cod(n):
    if n == "":
        return "" 
    else:
        a = str(ord(n[0])) + str(cod(n[1:]))
        return int(a)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is it. It's the solution PeterWood pointed out, i was overcomplicating :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to create another method for returning integer. Just to keep the code clean,

```
def cod(n):
    if n == "":
        return "" 
    else:
        a = str(ord(n[0])) + cod(n[1:])
        return a

def codI(n):
    return int(cod(n))


print type(codI("hello")) 
print type(cod("hello"))
```